# Lifetime annotation for closure argument

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'd like to make the following code compile:

```
struct Provider {}

impl Provider {
    fn get_string<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a str { "this is a string" }
}

fn main() {
    let provider = Provider{};
    let mut vec: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

    // PROBLEM: how do I say that this reference s here
    // needs to live as long as vec?
    let fun = |s: &str| {
        vec.push(s);
    };

    fun(provider.get_string());
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0d8e97b3ef5eaea8f58e03372b9f03bb&version=stable&backtrace=0)

This is the compile error that I get:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:9:22
  |
9 |     let mut vec: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
  |                      ^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 11:24...
 --> src/main.rs:11:25
  |
11|     let fun = |s: &str| {
  |                         ^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:12:18
  |
12|         vec.push(s);
  |                  ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 13:6...
 --> src/main.rs:13:7
  |
13|     };
  |       ^
note: ...so that variable is valid at time of its declaration
 --> src/main.rs:11:9
  |
11|     let fun = |s: &str| {
  |         ^^^
```

Comment: Uh! That's a fun one. Sometimes I really wish I could use `'provider` to say "the lifetime of that guy, there".

Comment: not sure how to make it work. As a workaround, maybe you could let the closure capture s from the environment too instead of passing it in as a parameter. Like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e7fd2f4ee7c58b9e592a1f060b2d396b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: @Shepmaster I've since found that as well. That is the solution that also works for the real problem :) Still, I'm quite surprised that's impossible to manually specify the type of `s` here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works just fine if remove all the lifetime annotations and let the compiler inference do its job:

```
struct Provider;

impl Provider {
    fn get_string(&self) -> &str { "this is a string" }
}

fn main() {
    let provider = Provider;
    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    let mut fun = |s| {
        vec.push(s);
    };

    fun(provider.get_string());
}
```

In short, there's no way to explicitly refer to the lifetime of a local variable, only function arguments. The compiler knows how to do it, though.

If you truly needed it, you could create a function to allow annotating the lifetimes:

```
fn thing<'a>(provider: &'a Provider) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut vec: Vec<&'a str> = Vec::new();

    {
        let mut fun = |s: &'a str| vec.push(s);

        fun(provider.get_string());
    } // End mutable borrow of `vec`

    vec
}

fn main() {
    let provider = Provider;
    thing(&provider);
}
```

> why did the original annotations stop things from working?

Specifically, it's this bit:

```
let fun = |s: &str| {
    vec.push(s);
};
```

This declares a new lifetime on the closure. Using a **made-up syntax** (you [can't declare lifetimes on closure arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31403723/155423)), it would be equivalent to:

```
let fun = <'a> |s: &'a str| {
    vec.push(s);
};
```

Which is why the compiler has the error:

> the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on [the closure's block]

There's no connection between that generated lifetime and that of the `Provider`. Leaving it out allows the compiler to insert the desired but unnamable lifetime.

Comment: Is there any work/proposal to make it possible to specify the type of `s` explictly in a future rust version? I guess what would be needed for that is some kind lifetime specification that says that the reference has the same lifetime as <other reference>, so I could write `|s: &'liftime_of(provider) str`

Comment: @bennofs I know of no such way or proposal to allow explicitly referring to the lifetime of a local variable.

Comment: today I learned that inference can be more powerful (vs just more convenient) than manually specifying lifetimes... Thanks for that!

Comment: @PaoloFalabella it was pretty confusing to me at first, because I always strive to remove any explicit lifetimes / types. At some point, I hit strange problems because a question asker had explicit lifetimes and I didn't, so I couldn't figure out what was broken. Now I remember.

Comment: Can you explain why the original annotations stopped things from working? None of them look different to me to what I'd expect the compiler to de-elide or infer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version which compiles:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Provider<'a> {
    _dummy: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> Provider<'a> {
    fn get_string(&self) -> &'a str {
        "this is a string"
    }
}

fn f<'b>() {
    let provider = Provider { _dummy: PhantomData };
    let mut vec: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();

    // PROBLEM: how do I say that this reference s here
    // needs to live as long as vec?
    let mut fun = |s: &'b str| { vec.push(s); };

    fun(provider.get_string());
}

fn main() {
    f()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ae8183a207a28d17557334c57d00739a&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I made the following changes:

- Add a lifetime to `Provider` (I added a `PhantomData`, but I guess your provider already owns some data it'll provide).
- Update the `get_string` method to show that it returns something with the provider's lifetime, not the input lifetime (ie based on the `Provider`'s lifetime parameter).
- Add a new lifetime parameter `'b` to the function (which I renamed to `f()`, since `main()` can't have one), which I use to name the lifetime of the closure parameter.

The last one is slightly confusing, as apparently merely adding a name to a lifetime (without apparently adding any constraints) has made it work.

I *think* (but I'd love some documentation for this) that this is because of lifetime elision.  A closure is really a hidden `struct` with a `fn call(&self, s: &str)` (in this case) method.  According to the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision), the `s` parameter gains the same lifetime as `&self`, which is the closure itself.  In this case, the closure is declared after `vec`, so the lifetime is too short.  The explicit lifetime means that it is decoupled from the closure's own lifetime.

Comment: This answer is certainly interesting and provided me some new infos about lifetimes, but unfortunately, in my problem, `Provider` is an `Arena` which does not have any data that it owns :( So the reference really does not live any longer than the provider itself.

Comment: What determins how long the result of `get_string` lives in your case?

Comment: It lives exactly as long as the `provider` does

Comment: In which case does the `PhantomData` not do what you want as in the answer?

Comment: Consider the case where the `String` owned by `Provider` (through an attribute for example). Example (edited wrong link): https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4c97845847bbda978b41f30b26a0f7db&version=stable&backtrace=0