# Can a standalone closure take `&str` and return `&str` with the same lifetime?

Tags: rust

Code:

```
fn main() {
    let f = |str: &str| str.trim();
    println!("{}", f("  foo bar  "));
}
```

Error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:25
  |
2 |     let f = |str: &str| str.trim();
  |                   -   - ^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                   |   |
  |                   |   return type of closure is &'2 str
  |                   let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2c98616c29fccff61cc38660fe25842)

The same closure works if used as an argument to a function, e.g. `vec.iter().map(|str| str.trim())`.

Is it possible for a standalone closure, like in my code, to take `&str` and return `&str` with the same lifetime?

Comment: TL;DR: no. [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c72c8152f84a33509f3376fe0369305).

Comment: Also, pay attention to [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198877/1600898) to the original question, which is much more useful than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks @user4815162342 and Shepmaster, I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the inference fails, but for some reason the borrow checker treats annotations on the closure differently from annotations on `fn`.

This works:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cfcfb4877894d3ed7fbce88bfeddb45c

```
fn main() {
    let f: fn(&str) -> &str = |s| s.trim();
    println!("{}", f("  foo bar  "));
}
```

Comment: `fn(&str) -> &str` causes the closure to be coerced to a function pointer, which (in this trivial case is likely the same, but) may inhibit inlining and/or require an indirection. Moreover, the closure can't capture anything, so you may as well just write `fn f(s: &str) -> &str { s.trim() }`. Shepmaster's answer to the linked question doesn't have either of these drawbacks.

Comment: This is a nice hack, I didn't know you could assign a closure to a variable of type `fn(...) -> ...`. But I suspect it won't help the OP's actual use case which likely requires a capturing closure which won't be `fn()`.